# Store OpenAM session attributes to cookie

Tags: openam

From my understanding user session info for OpenAM only can be access by Session API.  And we need to use post-auth plugin to extract those info and insert to cookie.

By question is:
- Without using post-auth plugin, is that a way to configure OpenAM (via UI) return specific user session attribute(s) (eg. AuthType) to it's cookie?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenAM policy agents can store session attributes to cookies or headers (see realm -> access control -> Agents -> Your agent -> application).

The other option would be to use OAuth flows (Open Identity Connect) - which can present user attributes in a JWT token as part of the authentication process. Your client would have to decode the JWT token and extract the attributes.

Comment: Hi, how to **present user attributes in a JWT token as part of the authentication proces**? I cannot find such settings.

Comment: In OpenAM 13 (under development) there is a scripted OpenID connect provider. A sample groovy script is provided that will add attributes to the JWT

Comment: So with OpenAM 12, adding attributes to JWT can via custom OAuth scope extension?

Comment: Yes - in OpenAM 12 you need to write a custom OAuth scope extension class. In OpenAM 13 the scripted claims provider is much easier - no Java required.